# Manually Change Scheme MVC 3 EF Code First

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-3, code-first

I'm putting together a website using MVC 3 EF Code-First that is connecting to SQL Server.

For some reason when I bring it up in SQL Server I only see four or five of the model classes in tables.

The one I modified is not there. I figured it wasn't created yet because no one had tried to put any data in it. Since it wasn't there I tried building and running the website from Visual Web Developer and it crashed when I tried to display my table.

I'm not sure how to manually update my table if it is missing from SQL Server.

Any guesses how I'm goofing this up?

EDIT: I've had some success with the Initializer classes, but I have a lot of tables and I am too lazy to add Initializer classes for all my tables when I can just modify the schema. (Is that kind of laziness bad?)

Answer (score 3):

Use this in startup of your application:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<YourContextType>());
```

It will force EF to delete and recreate your database every time you change your model classes. It should be used only for development.

Comment: Thanks, Ladislav. In case anyone is wondering this goes in your top-level Global.asax file in the Application_Start() function. You might need to add the using EF line at the top.